# Why does EF Core TPT create foreign keys to base type as well as derived types?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model where `Company` and `NaturalPerson` both inherit from `Person` (because a company is a legal person).

Both a company and a person can own stuff, so I have an `Ownership` object that simply references a `Person`, and that `Person` can either be a `Company` or a `NaturalPerson`.

When generating the model using TPT, I get a table for `Person`, a table for `Company` and a table for `NaturalPerson`. So far so good.

I also have a table for `Ownership`, in which I would expect to see only 1 foreign key to the `Person` table, but I see an extra 2 (making it 3 in total), to the `Company` and `NaturalPerson` tables.

Is that normal? And if yes, why?
Or did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's a piece of code that'll illustrate what I have:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NaturalPerson>().ToTable("NaturalPerson");
        modelBuilder.Entity<LegalPerson>().ToTable("LegalPerson");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff>().ToTable("CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("Company");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SharableGood>().ToTable("Good");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ownership>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Owner)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.OwnerId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ownership>()
            .HasOne(o => o.SharableGood)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.SharableGoodId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }
}

public abstract class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class NaturalPerson : Person
{
    public List<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}

public class LegalPerson : Person { }

public class CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff : LegalPerson { }

public class Company: LegalPerson
{
    public List<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}

public class SharableGood
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Ownership
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SharableGoodId { get; set; }
    public SharableGood SharableGood { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportantDate { get; set; }
}
```

The generated code for `Ownership` table looks like this:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Ownership",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        SharableGoodId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        OwnerId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        ImportantDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
        CompanyId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true),
        NaturalPersonId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Ownership", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Ownership_Company_CompanyId",
            column: x => x.CompanyId,
            principalTable: "Company",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Ownership_Good_SharableGoodId",
            column: x => x.SharableGoodId,
            principalTable: "Good",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Ownership_NaturalPerson_NaturalPersonId",
            column: x => x.NaturalPersonId,
            principalTable: "NaturalPerson",
            principalColumn: "Id");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Ownership_Person_OwnerId",
            column: x => x.OwnerId,
            principalTable: "Person",
            principalColumn: "Id");
    });
```

As you can see it also created the `CompanyId` and `NaturalPersonId` columns when really all I need is the `OwnerId`. The only reason I can think of for this behaviour is to make it easier to know what kind of entity the owner is, company or natural person.

Comment: Will be great to show some code

Comment: @DarkkL, done, sorry I didn't have time to do it earlier 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `FluentApi` at all to create tables and their relations in `EF Core`(except if you need one-to-one relation).

```
//Don't need Person in the db
public abstract class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class NaturalPerson : Person
{
    //Initialize the collection
    public NaturalPerson()
    {
        this.Ownerships = new HashSet<Ownership>();
    }
    
    //EF Core best practice for relation Many -
    public ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}

public class LegalPerson : Person
{
    public LegalPerson ()
    {
        this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        this.CompanyThatCannotOwnStuffs = new HashSet<CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff>();
    }

    public ICollection<CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff> CompanyThatCannotOwnStuffs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company > Companies { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff
{
    //Change inheritance of to LegalPerson to relation
    public LegalPerson LegalPerson { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Ownerships = new HashSet<Ownership>();
    }
    
    //Change inheritance of to LegalPerson to relation
    public LegalPerson LegalPerson { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}

public class SharableGood
{
    public SharableGood()
    {
        this.Ownerships = new HashSet<Ownership>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ownership> Ownerships { get; set; }
}

public class Ownership
{
    public Ownership()
    {
        this.NaturalPersons = new HashSet<NaturalPerson>();
        this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SharableGood SharableGood { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportantDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<NaturalPerson> NaturalPersons { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Add the models `DBSets` in the context. I'm not entirely sure what all the connections between the models are because you haven't described them, so there may be inaccuracies

```
public virtual DbSet<NaturalPerson > NaturalPerson { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<LegalPerson > LegalPerson { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff> CompanyThatCannotOwnStuff{ get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Company> Company{ get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<SharableGood> SharableGood{ get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Ownership> Ownership{ get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<NaturalPerson > NaturalPerson { get; set; }
```

Comment: The ownership object is the many-to-many link between sharable good and person, 1 person can have many sharable goods, and 1 sharable good can belong to many "persons" (remember company is a person). With what you provided, the ownership object links to an owner (person), to a sharable good, but also has a collection of companies and natural people... All I need is to understand why EF core generates those links even though I haven't specified them.